# Delete millions of objects from a folder in GCS bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a requirement where I need to delete millions of objects from a folder in a GCS bucket.
This is my current implementation.

```
bucket = self.storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=folder_name)
            
for blob in blobs:
    blob.delete()
```

As the number of objects is more, listing is not the right way. Need to find a way to do some multi-threading approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to delete the entire bucket objects, Setting bucket's lifecycle to 0 would be a way to fast deletion.

But this approach is not applied when you want to delete a folder(It is same as just deleting some part of entire object).

If the folder you want to delete takes up most of the entire objcet, I think deleting entire bucket through lifecycle management and creating new bucket with remainings can be more faster way.

Edit) gsutil rm command with `-m` flag can multi-threding deletion. This could be a faster way too.

Comment: Will "gsutil -m rm -R <folder_name>" work? Will it give better performance over the above implementation?

Comment: `gsutil -m rm`can remove files with multi-threding. It can be more faster way.

Comment: Sure, will try that.. Actually, I was aware of the gsutil way. Needed to know if it was possible by python. I think I will go with the gsutil way then,
Anyways, thanks for the help.. :)